# Creating classes from list in python

Tags: python, class, dynamic

I'd like to create classes from a list:

Super class
**BaseMethods.py**

```
class BaseMethods:
    def setData(self,newData):
       self.moduleData = newData

    def getData(self):
       return self.moduleData
```

Split classes by files
**ClassA.py**

```
import BaseMethods
class ClassA(BaseMethods):
    moduleId = None
    moduleData = None

    def __init__(self, moduleId, initData):
       super().__init__()
       self.moduleId = moduleId
       self.setData( initData)
```

**ClassB.py**

```
import BaseMethods
class ClassB(BaseMethods):
    moduleId = None
    moduleData = None

    def __init__(self,moduleId, initData):
       super().__init__()
       self.moduleId = moduleId
       self.setData(initData)
```

Main app

**main.py**

```
import random
from ClassA import ClassA
from ClassA import ClassB

myModules = {
   'module__1': ClassA,
   'module__2': ClassB,
}

interfaces = {}

def main():
  for moduleKey,moduleObj in myModules.items():
     initData = random.randint(0, 100)
     interfaces[moduleKey] = moduleObj(moduleKey, initData)

  for intKey,interface in interfaces.items():
     print(intKey,'=>',interface.getData())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But on execute

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\PROG\test\class\classTest_3.py", line 3, in <module>
 from ClassA import ClassA
 File "D:\PROG\test\class\ClassA.py", line 2, in <module>
 class ClassA(BaseMethods):
 TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Don't name the module and class the same `BaseMethods`, name the file with lowercase only like `base_methods`. Then `from base_methods import BaseMethods`

Comment: Even that's just a convention (though one you should follow). The main problem is that you didn't *distinguish* between the module named `BaseMethods` and the class `BaseMethods` defined in the module. (Another convention: the class name should probably be singular.)

Answer (score 0):

When doing `import BaseMethods`, you're importing the module (equivalent to the file), not the class which is what you actually need

---

What you need is

```py
# base_methods.py
class BaseMethods:
    def setData(self,newData):
       self.moduleData = newData

    def getData(self):
       return self.moduleData
```

```py
from base_methods import BaseMethods

class ClassA(BaseMethods):
    pass
```